# Photo Competition Rules

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

As our site continues to develop and grow, we will be starting a photo competition to increase community involvement and have a bit of fun. 
 The contest will take place every two weeks, and the theme of the contest will change each time. The theme could be anything from your favorite aerial landscape photo to your fastest racing drone!

As of right now, the rules for the photo competition are as follows:

- Only one photo per answer.
- A maximum of three answers per user.
- The photo must have been taken by the person who posted it, or by a friend or relative (must be named).
- Photos may have been taken at any time.
- list the year that the photo was taken.
- You may include a brief description of the photo (not required).
- All photos need to be nice and non-offensive.
- The winning photo will be the post with the most upvotes.
- Downvotes will not count towards the final score of a photo.
- The winning photo will be selected at the end of two weeks.
- The voting will begin at 0:00 UTC of every other Monday, and continue until the end of two weeks, at which point the winner will be selected and a new theme will be selected for the next competition.

This post is to discuss these rules, so let us know if you have any suggestions. And if you have any questions about the competition, feel free to ask. There is a [separate post](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/photo-competition-topics) for photo competition topic ideas.