# Photo Competition Topics

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

The Drones and Model Aircraft Photo Competition is designed to bring the community together while having a bit of fun. Each contest will have a set topic. If you have any topics that you would like to see in an upcoming photo contest, please leave them below in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two topics that I think would be cool are **Aerial landscape** (any picture of a landscape taken with a drone/model aircraft), and **Custom budget build** (A drone/model aircraft that you built on your own with inexpensive parts).